# Why does ruby throw error when calling to_sym against a select-one?

Tags: ruby, capybara

I'm running up against an error when I call to_sym against an element of type "select-one".

```
  begin
    ["//select", "//input"].each do |t|
      puts 'finding input for : ' + t
      elements = all(:xpath, t)
      elements.each do |e|
        puts "found element #{e[:id]} of type #{e[:type]}" if @debug
        puts "to symbol result: " + e[:id].to_sym  #This line explodes
        #...
  rescue
    puts "failed to enter fields on #{@name}"
    raise
  end
```

I get the error "Failed to enter fields on pageName".  This error occurs when I call `to_sym` on Element of type select-one.  How can I pinpoint the cause of this error and resolve it?

**UPDATE**

Per @axeltetzlaff I installed Pry.  I noticed the values[salutation] returns nil where I expect a value given below:

```
[1] pry(#<Step>)> values[e[:salutation]]
=> nil
[2] pry(#<Step>)> values
=> {:z=>"z",
 :a=>"a",
 :b=>"b",
 :c=>"c",
 :d=>"d",
 :e=>"e",
 :f=>"f",
 :g=>"",
 :h=>"",
 :salutation=>"Mr.",#See...I have a value
```

**Update2**

I took out the `puts` I am using for debugging and the issue went away:

`puts "to symbol result: " + e[:id].to_sym  #This line explodes`

The code no longer breaks on the next line.  By simple deduction, the issue is that I cannot concatenate a string and a symbol.  I am guessing there is some ruby rule somewhere that says I can't do this, but I do not have one available.

Comment: put a debugger before that line and investigate on the type and contents of `e` in the interactive debugger

Comment: I tried installing an interactive debugger about 6 months ago with no success.  I will attempt the process again.

Comment: Yeah I know, it can be a major pita - but once it works you'll never want to let go of it ;-) check out byebug if you're on a recent ruby version http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#setup

Comment: I've got pry going.  Tinkering with it to see how I explore total contents list.  I got some results out of it that I added with K M 's answer below.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey you have to do: `values[:salutation]` NOT `values[e[:salutation]]`

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam You are right.  That helped me figure out what's happening.  See question update.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Look at my edited answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`to_sym` converts a string to a symbol. For example, `"a".to_sym` becomes `:a`

Make sure your `e[:id]` returns a string object on which you are calling `to_sym` method. Try inspecting:

```
puts e[:id].inspect
puts e[:id].class
```

#### Update:

You can't concat a string and a symbol in Ruby. That will throw `no implicit conversion of Symbol into String (TypeError)` exception.

Instead of doing:

```
puts "to symbol result: " + e[:id].to_sym
```

you could do the same thing using string interpolation like this:

```
puts "to symbol result: #{e[:id].to_sym}"
```

Comment: `e[:id].class => String` and `e[:id].inspect => "\"salutation\""`

Comment: This one is OK.
As you are looping through the elements. May be, one of your element's id  is not returning a string. If you post the full code, I can try it locally to see what's going on.

Comment: Its not a different element because I print out each element in the loop.  This element fails (code is above).  The code never makes it past the very next call after these debug results (marked "this line explodes).

Comment: Instead of `puts` better use `p` or [pp](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/PP.html) for debugging purposes.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Better use _byebug_ or any kind of debugger to sit between the good and bad code, and inspect what is going on. BTW, what is your Ruby version ?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Can you show the full error stack ?

Comment: Per all the useful feedback, I updated the question.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey please share the full stack trace to help us understand the problem as per Arup's suggestion. Also, the full code snippet if possible.